# How to validate date in DB2

Tags: sql, date, validation, datetime, db2

Changed DATE field to DT to avoid confusions
Editing question with the full query for more clarity

```
SELECT
    S1.NR AS "a",
    S1.ZTV AS "b",
    S1.RNR AS "c",
    S1.TW AS "d",
    S1.STV AS "e",
    S1.RTV "f",
    S1.DA AS "v",
    CASE 
        WHEN S1.ZTV = '115' THEN 'T_RR' 
        ELSE ' ' 
    END AS "DT",
    ' ' AS "SiT",
    S1.S1JL AS "Ns",
    S1.S1JM AS "Vs",
    S1.S1JN AS "NSv",
    S1.S1JO AS "VSf",
    S1.S1JP AS "Vse",
    S1.S1JQ AS "Vde",
    S1.S1JR AS "Vds" 
CASE WHEN S1.DT != '0001-01-01' THEN S1.DT
ELSE ' '
END as "SlDate"
FROM
    XXXX S1 
JOIN
    YYYYY B 
        ON S1.STW = B.BCD 
        AND  (
            CASE 
                WHEN B1.BUSX != ' ' 
                AND S1.S1TV = B1.BTX THEN 1 
                WHEN S1.S1TV = B1.B2TX THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END) =1
```

How can I validate date in DB2. I have a column which columns values like '0001-01-01'
I have a condition to display dates only when it is valid.

```
CASE WHEN S1.DT != '0001-01-01' THEN S1.DT ELSE ' ' END
```

I am getting below error while executing the query. What could be the issue here?

This condition fails while executing query.
 SQL State: 42815 Vendor Code: -171 Message: [SQL0171] Argument 1 of function CASE not valid. Cause . . . . . :   The data type, length, or value of argument 1 of function CASE specified is not valid. Recovery  . . . :   Refer to the DB2 for IBM i SQL Reference topic collection in the Database category in the IBM i Information Center for more information on scalar functions. Correct the arguments specified for the function. Try the request again.

Comment: Use UDF with an exception handler, if the question is about how to validate a string representation of date. Provide an example of your full code otherwise.

Comment: I have posted full query. Can you please help here

Comment: You missed a comma before the CASE expression you mentioned.
Run the following statement as is.
`SELECT
  S1.DT
, CASE WHEN S1.DT != '0001-01-01' THEN S1.DT ELSE ' ' END as "SlDate" 
FROM (VALUES '0001-01-01', '0001-01-02') S1 (DT)`
Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perhaps unfortunate that you have named the column DATE, which is an SQL reserved word, so it may cause confusion.  Anyway, I would expect to see your CASE statement written as below, because the result of both the THEN clause and the ELSE clause need to be of the same datatype, in this case DATE.  Hence use CAST(NULL AS DATE) rather than ''.  On the other hand, if you want the result to be of type CHAR or VARCHAR then you need to cast the date to character e.g. using TO_CHAR(S1.DATE) and you can then keep the ELSE part as ''.

`CASE WHEN S1.DATE != '0001-01-01' THEN S1.DATE ELSE CAST(NULL AS DATE) END as "SlDate"`

Or

`CASE WHEN S1.DATE != '0001-01-01' THEN TO_CHAR(S1.DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ELSE '' END as "SlDate"`

Answer (score 1):

Your `dt` column is a `date` and the string value `' '` is *not* a `date`.  A `case` expression returns a single type.  Because one return path is `date`, the rules of SQL choose `date` over a string.

There is a built-in function to turn the value to `NULL`, which is what I recommend:

```
NULLIF(S1.DT, '0001-01-01')
```

DB2 is smart enough to convert the `'0001-01-01'` to a date.  But you can also be explicit that the constant is a date:

```
NULLIF(S1.DT, DATE '0001-01-01')
```

If you really want to use a string for the bad value, then you need to convert the to strings.  In that case, `case` is probably the simplest solution:

```
(CASE WHEN S1.DT = DATE '0001-01-01'
      THEN TO_CHAR(s1.DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      ELSE ' '
 END)
```